# Google Cloud Java API calls from a servlet: blocking or connection concerns?

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, web-applications, libraries

Just trying out the Java API for GCP (the compute lib).  I'm making calls to the API from a servlet ...

```
Compute.Instances.Insert insert = compute.instances().insert("tester", "us-easts1-db", instance);
Operation o = insert.execute();
```

The docs read that this is an asynch call (non-blocking), but, this will ultimately mean there will be child thread(s) created, and the servlet is going to return a response without checking (or waiting for) the status of the operation.  Can anyone confirm (I'm little lazy to dig through the source) that they've made such calls from a servlet and did not experience any issues with memory leaks or problems (such as connections not being closed) due to making the calls from a servlet?

I've read a ton of the docs and have the code for two sample compute apps, but have yet to see any example code showing API calls made from a servlet (and the compute API seems to be only in alpha right now).

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to ask your question on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com) and/or ask your question directly to engineers on [github](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-java/issues) as you should get much better result in term of answers.

> Server Fault is for system administrators and desktop support
>   professionals, people who manage or maintain computers in a
>   professional capacity.

Comment: ok, thanks for the clarity - wasn't clear on the scope and relationship between these two sites